# Allocating memory for my struct failing with segfault, unknown address

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Hard to give a short description.

my_queue.h:

```c
...
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 1025 // characters in each string
#define MAX_QUEUE_CAPACITY 20  // queue capacity
#define UNINITIALIZED -1000

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    char (*data)[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]; // declare a pointer that
                                     // can point to whole array
    int head;
    int tail;
    int count;
    int is_mt_safe;
    sem_t items_available;
    sem_t space_available;
    sem_t mutex;
} queue;
...
```

Here is how I was doing it before:

my_queue.c:

```c
...
queue *make_queue(char *name, int size, int mt_safe)
{
    queue *new = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    new->name = name;
    new->is_mt_safe = mt_safe;
    new->head = 0;
    new->count = 0;
    ...
```

I didn't initialize `queue->data` at all. Instead, I just started writing to it
in `my_queue_push`:

```
strcpy(q->data[q->tail], str);
```

This (or something similar, I'd have to go back and check)
used to work, but I decided to re-work my implementation of the queue
because I realized I had misunderstood my requirements, and I wanted to make
the queue grow as necessary rather than be statically sized.

Back then, I had the queue->data defined differently, as a 2-dimensional char array,
rather than a pointer. (Something like `char data[MAX_QUEUE_CAPACITY][MAX_STRING_LENGTH]`). As part of making the queue dynamic, I tried to use a pointer to a set of arrays instead of a 2-dimensional char array.

Now I am seeing segfaults when I try to run the line in `queue_push`. I thought maybe it was a few different problems (various array initialization issues), but I used AddressSanitizer and I THINK I have it narrowed down to the address being 0x0000..., which seems like an issue with my malloc'ing the queue->data incorrectly.

> AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
> =================================================================
> ==245048==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7fdec87b4e1f bp 0x7ffe5cab87b0 sp 0x7ffe5cab7f20
> T0)
> ==245048==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
> ==245048==Hint: address points to the zero page.
> #0 0x7fdec87b4e1e  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x9be1e)
> #1 0x55e94a06dcca in queue_push /home/brian/Workspace/MT-dns-resolver/mt-cirque.c:102
> #2 0x55e94a06c895 in main /home/brian/Workspace/MT-dns-resolver/multi-lookup.c:28
> #3 0x7fdec854e0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
> #4 0x55e94a06c6ad in _start (/home/brian/Workspace/MT-dns-resolver/multi-lookup+0x26ad)

I thought of maybe malloc'ing the queue->data separately, but I can't work out how to do that if appropriate.

My code likely has some issues as I have bootstrapped myself into writing C very quickly. Obvious things are that `strcpy` maybe doesn't work with a pointer to a char array? I have gone back and forth on this and I see people having issues similar to but not exactly that on SO.

Please be forgiving. Let me know if you need more information or if I made an obvious mistake, but...

... What am I doing wrong here, do you think? Thanks.

Comment: `q->data` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere. When dereferencing that pointer then it leads to *undefined behavior* and very likely crashes. All pointers must be initialized to actually point somewhere.

Comment: Ok. I get that that makes sense. A smaller domain of questions in my mind then. Where should I make it point, given that it's a member of this struct, which itself has been allocated at a certain address? As I mentioned, I tried to allocate memory for q->data itself (leaving my `malloc` for the queue in `make_queue` as it is), and I get a weird error about using the heap wrong.

Comment: First you need to tell us what `q->data` is really supposed to be. Is it supposed to be an array of strings? Then you could do `q->data = malloc(MAX_QUEUE_CAPACITY * sizeof *q->data)` to allocate `MAX_QUEUE_CAPACITY` number of strings.

Comment: It's supposed to be an array of strings, yes.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, and then, should I make  `queue *new = malloc(sizeof(queue) * size);` something like `queue *new;` and not allocate space for the struct? I need to go review struct usage I guess.

Comment: Your current allocation of the `queue` structure itself is fine as it is. With `malloc(sizeof(queue) * size)` you would create an array of `size` queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the data as well, as otherwise the `data` pointer won't point anywhere useful:

```
queue *make_queue(char *name, int size, int mt_safe)
{
    // Allocate memory for the structure itself
    queue *new = malloc(sizeof *new);

    // Allocate memory for the strings in the queue
    // There will be `size` elements in the array of strings
    new->data = malloc(size * sizeof *new->data);

    ...
}
```

After this `q->data` can be used as an array of strings.

Comment: Great! I used that line and it actually worked. Not sure why I was getting a weird error about the heap before. Out of curiosity, why is it `sizeof(*new->data)` in `new->data = malloc( * sizeof(*new->data))`? Why the value of new->data?

Comment: @BrianPeterson Since `new->data` is a pointer to `char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]`, `sizeof(*new->data)` will be `sizeof(char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH])`. Using the pointer variable is shorter, and will always be correct.